# Microsoft CRM 4 : What user privileges are needed to access the webservice API?

Tags: web-services, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I am trying to use the Microsoft CRM 4 webservices. However, I get the 401 Unauthorized error for any requests I send. I am running under my own user account, which has access to CRM.

What user privileges do I need to add, in order to get access ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind.

The problem was that `OrganizationName` on `CrmAuthenticationToken` must be set correctly, or you will get a 401 Unauthorized. I had made a typo when putting it in.